# Understanding bijection from to/from multiset

Tags: combinatorics, intuition

I'm playing a peculiar lottery. We pick $5$ numbers from $\{1, ..., 9\}$, order doesn't matter, repetition is allowed.

The question here is, how many $5$ element multisets can I create from $\{1, ..., 9\}$. To solve the problem and get an intuition, I made use of a mental model called "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))".

Imagine 5 buckets. Now we sort $9$ items into these $5$ buckets. We can represent such an arrangement like so:

```
**|****|***||
```

The above could be represented as a $5$-tuple like so $(2, 4, 3, 0, 0)$, meaning we put $2$ items in the first bucket, $4$ items in the second etc.

We have $9$ stars to represent the items, and $5-1=4$ bars to segregate the buckets.

In general we have $9 + 5 - 1=13$ slots, onto which we distribute $9$ stars and $4$ bars as separators.

For the $9$ stars, there are $13! / 5!$ ways to arrange them, and since order doesn't matter among the stars, we divide by another $9!$ to find the count of all possible stars/bars arrangements:

$$\frac{13!}{9!5!} = \binom{9 + 5 - 1}{5}$$

But what I don't understand is, the above counts the ways how to create $5$-tuples like $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$ etc. But how does this relate to $5$-element multisets chosen from $\{1, ..., 9\}$ ?

In other words, for a given $5$-tuple, what's the bijection onto multisets from $\{1, ..., 9\}$?

My conjecture:

- In total there are $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to find a set of $5$ unique numbers $A=\{n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5\}$.
- Now I want to create multisets of $5$ numbers from $A$. Each number $n_i$ can appear at most $5$ times in a multiset, and at least $0$ times. That is what the $5$-tuple found by stars and bars represents, say $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$. If $a_i=1$, let $n_1$ appear 1 time, etc.

I'm not sure if the above makes sense, I have my doubts. Hence my question, how to think about relating the tuples found via the stars/bars method back to the original question about multisets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stars and bars, but the buckets should represent the numbers $1$ through $9$, and you should have $5$ balls, one for each pot. For instance, the arrangement

$$\mid\;\mid**\mid\;\mid\;\mid*\mid\;\mid**\;\mid$$

corresponds to the multiset $\lbrace\!\lbrace 3,3,6,8,8\rbrace\!\rbrace$. Now you have any string of $5$ stars and $8$ bars, so there are altogether

$$\binom{5+8}5=\binom{13}8=\binom{13}5=1287$$

multisets of $5$ elements from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense. In general I get confused by this quite often, is there any intuition as to what are the buckets and what are the items? Because I was quite confident I got it right, until I didn't.

Comment: @Max: In general it’s going to depend very much on the specific setting. In the context of multisets, though, it’s fairly straightforward: the balls will always be counters telling you how often each pot is used, so the pots will correspond to the possible elements, and you’ll have one ball for each member of the multiset.

Comment: Nice, now I get it. I knew that the | were used to separate the buckets, but now I also understand that the * are used as counter.

Comment: That's not the value I get for $\binom{13}{5}$.

Comment: @celtschk: You’re absolutely right: I apparently neglected to divide by $5!$. Thanks!